# Write an explicit form

Tags: list-manipulation

In general for a natural number N and any vector of size 1*(2N+1)2^{N+1}, I need

```
a[-1, -2] = v[[1]], a[-1, -1] = v[[2]], a[-1, 0] = v[[3]], 
a[-1, 1] = v[[4]], a[0, -2] = v[[5]], a[0, -1] = v[[6]], 
a[0, 0] = v[[7]], a[0, 1] = v[[8]], a[1,-2] = v[[9]], 
a[1, -1] = v[[10]], a[1, 0] = v[[11]], a[1, 1] = v[[12]].....
a[-N,2^(N)-1]=(2N+1)2^{N}-1.
```

As an example and for N=1, let `v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}` (or any vector of size 1*12); Now how to assign the values as follows

```
a[-1, -2] = v[[1]]=1, a[-1, -1] = v[[2]]=2, a[-1, 0] = v[[3]]=3, 
a[-1, 1] = v[[4]]=4, a[0, -2] = v[[5]]=5, a[0, -1] = v[[6]]=6, 
a[0, 0] = v[[7]]=7, a[0, 1] = v[[8]]=8, a[1,-2] = v[[9]]=9, 
a[1, -1] = v[[10]]=10, a[1, 0] = v[[11]]=11, a[1, 1] = v[[12]]=12
```

Comment: `k = 0; Do[ a[i, j] = v[[++k]] , {i, -1, 1} , {j, -2, 1}];`  ??

Comment: alternately compute your sum as a dot product: `Dot[Flatten[Table[Sin[2^j x - k], {j, -1, 1}, {k, -2, 1}], 1], v]`

Comment: @george2079 thank you so much. Your first code works perfectly. Appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what is mean the up-voted I did. What I meant is that I really appreciated @george2079 suggested code. I hope someone can provide me with the guidelines and policy on how to use the website as I am new to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
k = 0; 
Do[ a[i, j] = v[[++k]] , {i, -1, 1} , {j, -2, 1}];
```

Thank you George2079 I voted to your answer as it solved the issue I had!